# Battery life of laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, sleep

I bought laptop in 2019 specs- i5,2tb hdd and Windows 10 and from then I am keeping my laptop on sleep mode.

After 4-5 months I started facing battery issues like battery life was around only 1.2 hrs or less and my laptop became very slow.

This happened to me yesterday when I was using my laptop it was on charging and after 100% charge I unplugged it and it discharged very fast, I plugged it again and after full charge i unplugged it and in less than 1hr it got discharged to 10%. This all happens to me in timespan of 2hrs.

So my question is does sleep mode affect battery life or not?

Comment: Check that you don't have malware or some software permanently running and using 100% of tour CPU. If your CPU is permanently at its top frequency then that will have a big effect on power.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend does not harm or reduce battery life normally.

Keeping it on Full Charge at all other times will more likely reduce battery life.

A laptop always plugged in needs Battery Threshold Management and set to 80% charge (widely accepted constant on rate for being always plugged in).

If you cannot set Threshold (not supported in your BIOS), then charge it, unplug and use it, charge it .... and so on.

You may need to replace this battery.